# Authorization for azure app resource management without client ID and client secret

Tags: azure, go, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create an application where the user can manage their Azure resources (sql databases, storage). How can I authorize the  user without needing their client ID and client secret.

I've looked at their documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth, however all of them requires environment variables and/or clientID/clientSecret. Is there a way where a user can provide username/password and I can get back an authorizer

```
type Client struct {
    ServersClient postgresql.ServersClient
}

func NewCloudClient() *Client {
    return &Client{}
}

func (c *Client) Init(config map[string]string) error {
    var (
        subscriptionID = config["subscriptionID"]
        // tenantID       = config["tenantID"]
        // clientID       = config["clientID"]
        // clientSecret   = config["clientSecret"]
        // resourceGroup  = config["resourceGroup"]
    )
    // oauthConfig, err := adal.NewOAuthConfig(azure.PublicCloud.ActiveDirectoryEndpoint, tenantID)
    // if err != nil {
    //  return errors.Wrap(err, "error getting OAuthConfig")
    // }
    // spt, err := adal.NewServicePrincipalToken(*oauthConfig, clientID, clientSecret, resourceGroup)
    serversClient := postgresql.NewServersClient(subscriptionID)

    //serversClient.BaseClient.Authorizer = autorest.NewBearerAuthorizer(spt)
    c.ServersClient = serversClient
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **all cases** of authorization flow you will need at least **client id**. In some you will need more like **client secret**.

You can read about OAuth authorization here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-app-types

but in general what you are aiming for is either of two cases

1. Authorize as user without internaction using username and password (this would be client **resource owner flow**

   - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc
2. Authorize as user with his interaction

   - if  this is code that can't get postback URL then use **device code flow** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code
   - or for anything in the browser use standard **implicit grant flow** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

You will quickly notice that in all cases you NEED to have client ID. This is because how Azure Authentication works.

Comment: And do not pick Resource Owner Password Credentials flow (option 1). Your app should never be handling the user's password.

Comment: You can also use a multi-tenant app, though a user will then need to give your app the necessary RBAC roles manually, or you can do it automatically by using the logged-in user's access to create the RBAC assignments.

Comment: Agreed. But in some rare cases ROPC is the only way, but should be avoided if possible. Otherwise ROPC wouldn't exist. Hard to say what OP is doing.